# How fast would someone travel by jumping out of a spaceship into space

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity

If someone without any propulsion jumped from a stationary ship in space, how fast would they travel?

Comment: You should be a little bit more detailed about what exactly you would like to know, as there are many possible ways that one could answer this.

Comment: What is "stationary...in space" supposed to mean?  Stationary relative to what?  And can you quantify "jumped"?  (I mean, Jumped how hard?)

Comment: Sorry to be cryptic. Imagine you are in a space station, orbiting the earth. You jump out the door. how fast would you, (the average human), be traveling? Is 9 mph a good estimate?

Answer (score 2):

The highest a good athlete can jump on the earth's surface, where the acceleration due to gravity is about 32 feet per second squared, is about 3 feet.  If the initial velocity from the jump is $v$, then the athlete's height at time $t$ is $vt-16t^2$.  This is maximized at $t=v/32$, where the height is $v^2/64$.  This gives $v^2/64=3$, or (roughly) $v=14$.  So the athlete can achieve an initial velocity of about $14$ feet per second --- call it 9 miles per hour --- and of course in space you'd maintain this velocity pretty much forever.

(If you can jump either more or less than 3 feet off the ground, then, of course, correct the arithmetic accordingly to get your own speed in space.)re

Comment: The world record for the highest standing jump is an impressive [6'3"](http://www.sportingnews.com/nba-news/4642213-jordan-kilganon-dunker-75-inch-box-jump-world-record), giving 20 feet per second.

Comment: @pela That is a little bit of an overestimate. Really good high jumpers manage to move their bodies over the bar while their center of mass passes *under* the bar. It helps to be very limber indeed. And yes it seems to be a small fractional effect but the square make for twice the fractional effect.

Comment: And the center of mass *starts* 3 or 4 feet above the ground...

Comment: @dmckee. In [high jump](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_jump), you're right that the CoM doesn't go as high. I hadn't considered that. But this was a [*box jump*](http://www.crossfitatmkg.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/Joes-Box-Jump.jpg), where the CoM is maybe a foot or more _over_ the edge. But as DJohnM says, the CoM _starts_ several feet above the ground.

Answer (score 1):

Velocities always have to be expressed with respect to some reference. When we talk about velocities on Earth, it's usually understood that we mean with respect to the surface of the Earth. If an astronaut on the ISS steps outside of the station, her velocity wrt. to ISS is (close to) zero, but wrt. to Earth's surface, it's 7.7 km/s, because this is the speed of the ISS wrt. Earth's surface. Wrt. Sun's surface, she would travel roughly 30 km/s, because this is Earth's speed around the Sun. Similarly, her speed wrt. the center of the Milky Way would be ~250 km/s, and so on.

Along the same lines, when you say "a stationary ship in space", you need to specify "stationary wrt. what?". It will always have some non-zero velocity wrt. something.

Comment: I thought it was pretty clear that the question was asking for the jumper's velocity relative to the ship.

Comment: @WillO: I wouldn't say it's pretty clear, but +1 for your interpretation and calculations.